# Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

este es el codigo html no se porque motivo no se pude cambiar la clase de icono con classList , me sale este error Cannot read property 'classList' of null

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preload" type="text/css" href="build/css/app.css" as="style">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="build/css/app.css">
    <title>Validar Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="contenedor">
        <form class="formulario" id="formulario">
          <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo">
            <label class="formulario__label" for="usuario">Usuario</label>
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                <input class="formulario__input" type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="formulario__input-error">El usuario tiene que ser de 4 a 16 digitos y solo puede contener numeros,letras y guion bajo.</p>
          </div>
          <!--Grupo nombre-->
          
          <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__nombre">
            <label class="formulario__label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                <input class="formulario__input"  type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="formulario__input-error">El usuario tiene que ser de 4 a 16 digitos y solo puede contener numeros,letras y guion bajo.</p>
          </div> 
          <!--Grupo contraseña-->   

          <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__password">
            <label class="formulario__label" for="password">Contraseña</label>
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                <input class="formulario__input"  type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="on">
                <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="formulario__input-error">La contraseña tiene que ser de 4 a 12 digitos</p>
          </div>

          <!--Grupo contraseña 2-->
          <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__password2">
            <label class="formulario__label" for="password2">Repetir contraseña</label>
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                <input class="formulario__input"  type="password" name="password2" id="password2" autocomplete="on">
                <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="formulario__input-error">Ambas contraseñas deben ser iguales</p>
          </div>
   
           <!--Grupo correo-->

           <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__correo">
            <label class="formulario__label" for="correo">Correo Electronica</label>
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                <input class="formulario__input"  type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo">
                <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="formulario__input-error">El correo solo puede contener letras , numeros , puntos , guiones y guion bajo. </p>
          </div>
           <!--Grupo telefono-->
           <div class="formulario__grupo" id="grupo__telefono">
            <label class="formulario__label" for="telefono">Telefono</label>
            <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
                <input class="formulario__input"  type="tel" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="+506 8834-1266">
                <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <p class="formulario__input-error">El telefono solo puede contener numeros y el maximo son 12 digitos. </p>
          </div>
          <!--Grupos: Terminos Y condiciones-->

          <div class="formulario__grupo formulario__grupo-terminos" id="grupo__terminos">
            <label class="formulario__label" for="terminos">
              <input  class="formulario__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos">
              Acepto los terminos y condiciones
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="formulario__mensaje" id="formulario__mensaje">
            <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> <b>Error:</b>Por favor rellene el formualrio correctamente</p>
          </div>
          <div class="formulario__grupo formulario__grupo-btn-enviar">
            <button type="submit" class="formulario__btn">Enviar</button>
            <p class="formulario__mensaje-exito" id="formulario__mensaje-exito">El formulario se envio exitosamente</p>
          </div>
        </form>
    </main>
    <script src="build/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>-->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

quiero cambiarle la clase del icono con classList pero me sale este error Cannot read property 'classList' of null ,quiero solucionarlo me gustaria un poco de ayuda , el problema esta en clases de los icono. He buscado en toda parte pero no he tenido exito.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLInputElement.validarFormulario

```js
const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#formulario input");
const expresiones = {
    usuario: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{4,16}$/, // Letras, numeros, guion y guion_bajo
    nombre: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,40}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.
    password: /^.{4,12}$/, // 4 a 12 digitos.
    correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
    telefono: /^\d{8,12}$/ // 7 a 14 numeros.
}

const validarFormulario = (e) => {
switch (e.target.name){
    case "usuario":
      if (expresiones.usuario.test(e.target.value)) {
        document.getElementById("grupo__usuario").classList.remove("formulario__grupo-incorrecto");
        document.getElementById("grupo__usuario").classList.add("formulario__grupo-correcto");
         document.querySelector("#grupo__usuario i").classList.add("  fa-check-circle");
        document.querySelector("#grupo__usuario i").classList.remove(" fa-times-circle");
       document.querySelector("#grupo__usuario .formulario__input-error").classList.remove("formulario__input-error-activo");  

      }else{
          document.getElementById("grupo__usuario").classList.add("formulario__grupo-incorrecto");
          document.getElementById("grupo__usuario").classList.remove("formulario__grupo-correcto");
          document.querySelector("#grupo__usuario i").classList.add(" fa-times-circle");
          document.querySelector("#grupo__usuario i").classList.remove("  fa-check-circle");
           document.querySelector("#grupo__usuario .formulario__input-error").classList.add("formulario__input-error-activo");  

      }     
    break;
    
 }

}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
 input.addEventListener("keyup", validarFormulario);
 input.addEventListener("blur", validarFormulario);

});

formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) =>{

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: No está claro en que línea se esta produciendo el error pero el mensaje parece bastante claro, el objeto que sea estás intentando recuperar con getElementById o con querySelector no está definido en tu HTML. Mira en qué línea te está dando el error y verifica que dicho elemento existe. Tampoco es muy recomendable usar espacios en los id de los elementos, eso también puede ser causa de error.

Comment: Pon el código HTML, lo que está claro es que no encuentra algún elemento pero sin el código HTML no se ve en qué línea se produce el error y por tanto cual es su origen.

Comment: hola mi amigo ahi puse el codigo html intente lo que me dijiste pero me sale el mismo error , lo que estoy intentando es cambiarle la clase al icono dee font awesone

Comment: Me podrias explicar porque si marque tu pregunta anterior como duplicada, que era exactamente igual a esta, la volviste a poner? si crees que la duplicada no soluciona tu problema, explica porque....

Comment: ya lo resolvi amigo el problema estaba el cdn